# Java - reading, manipulating and writing WAV files

Tags: java, audio, wav

In a Java program, what is the best way to read an audio file ([WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) file) to an array of numbers (`float[]`, `short[]`, ...), and to write a WAV file from an array of numbers?

Answer (score 15):

I read WAV files via an `AudioInputStream`. The following snippet from the [Java Sound Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html) works well.

```
int totalFramesRead = 0;
File fileIn = new File(somePathName);
// somePathName is a pre-existing string whose value was
// based on a user selection.
try {
  AudioInputStream audioInputStream = 
    AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
  int bytesPerFrame = 
    audioInputStream.getFormat().getFrameSize();
    if (bytesPerFrame == AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED) {
    // some audio formats may have unspecified frame size
    // in that case we may read any amount of bytes
    bytesPerFrame = 1;
  } 
  // Set an arbitrary buffer size of 1024 frames.
  int numBytes = 1024 * bytesPerFrame; 
  byte[] audioBytes = new byte[numBytes];
  try {
    int numBytesRead = 0;
    int numFramesRead = 0;
    // Try to read numBytes bytes from the file.
    while ((numBytesRead = 
      audioInputStream.read(audioBytes)) != -1) {
      // Calculate the number of frames actually read.
      numFramesRead = numBytesRead / bytesPerFrame;
      totalFramesRead += numFramesRead;
      // Here, do something useful with the audio data that's 
      // now in the audioBytes array...
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) { 
    // Handle the error...
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  // Handle the error...
}
```

To write a WAV, I found that quite tricky. On the surface it seems like a circular problem, the command that writes relies on an `AudioInputStream` as a parameter.

But how do you write bytes to an `AudioInputStream`? Shouldn't there be an `AudioOutputStream`?

What I found was that one can define an object that has access to the raw audio byte data to implement `TargetDataLine`.

This requires a lot of methods be implemented, but most can stay in dummy form as they are not required for writing data to a file. The key method to implement is `read(byte[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int numberofbytestoread)`.

As this method will probably be called multiple times, there should also be an instance variable that indicates how far through the data one has progressed, and update that as part of the above `read` method.

When you have implemented this method, then your object can be used in to create a new `AudioInputStream` which in turn can be used with:

```
AudioSystem.write(yourAudioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.WAV, yourFileDestination)
```

> As a reminder, an `AudioInputStream` can be created with a `TargetDataLine` as a source.

As to the direct manipulating the data, I have had good success acting on the data in the buffer in the innermost loop of the snippet example above, `audioBytes`.

While you are in that inner loop, you can convert the bytes to integers or floats and multiply a `volume` value (ranging from `0.0` to `1.0`) and then convert them back to little endian bytes.

I believe since you have access to a series of samples in that buffer you can also engage various forms of DSP filtering algorithms at that stage. In my experience I have found that it is better to do volume changes directly on data in this buffer because then you can make the smallest possible increment: one delta per sample, minimizing the chance of clicks due to volume-induced discontinuities.

I find the "control lines" for volume provided by Java tend to situations where the jumps in volume will cause clicks, and I believe this is because the deltas are only implemented at the granularity of a single buffer read (often in the range of one change per 1024 samples) rather than dividing the change into smaller pieces and adding them one per sample. But I'm not privy to how the Volume Controls were implemented, so please take that conjecture with a grain of salt.

All and all, Java.Sound has been a real headache to figure out. I fault the Tutorial for not including an explicit example of writing a file directly from bytes. I fault the Tutorial for burying the best example of Play a File coding in the "How to Convert..." section. However, there's a LOT of valuable FREE info in that tutorial.

---

EDIT: 12/13/17

I've since used the following code to write audio from a PCM file in my own projects. Instead of implementing `TargetDataLine` one can extend `InputStream` and use that as a parameter to the `AudioSystem.write` method.

```
public class StereoPcmInputStream extends InputStream
{
    private float[] dataFrames;
    private int framesCounter;
    private int cursor;
    private int[] pcmOut = new int[2];
    private int[] frameBytes = new int[4];
    private int idx;
    
    private int framesToRead;

    public void setDataFrames(float[] dataFrames)
    {
        this.dataFrames = dataFrames;
        framesToRead = dataFrames.length / 2;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException
    {
        while(available() > 0)
        {
            idx &= 3; 
            if (idx == 0) // set up next frame's worth of data
            {
                framesCounter++; // count elapsing frames

                // scale to 16 bits
                pcmOut[0] = (int)(dataFrames[cursor++] * Short.MAX_VALUE);
                pcmOut[1] = (int)(dataFrames[cursor++] * Short.MAX_VALUE);
            
                // output as unsigned bytes, in range [0..255]
                frameBytes[0] = (char)pcmOut[0];
                frameBytes[1] = (char)(pcmOut[0] >> 8);
                frameBytes[2] = (char)pcmOut[1];
                frameBytes[3] = (char)(pcmOut[1] >> 8);
            
            }
            return frameBytes[idx++]; 
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override 
    public int available()
    {
        // NOTE: not concurrency safe.
        // 1st half of sum: there are 4 reads available per frame to be read
        // 2nd half of sum: the # of bytes of the current frame that remain to be read
        return 4 * ((framesToRead - 1) - framesCounter) 
                + (4 - (idx % 4));
    }    

    @Override
    public void reset()
    {
        cursor = 0;
        framesCounter = 0;
        idx = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {
        System.out.println(
            "StereoPcmInputStream stopped after reading frames:" 
                + framesCounter);
    }
}
```

The source data to be exported here is in the form of stereo floats ranging from -1 to 1. The format of the resulting stream is 16-bit, stereo, little-endian.

I omitted `skip` and `markSupported` methods for my particular application. But it shouldn't be difficult to add them if they are needed.

Answer (score 14):

This is the source code to write directly to a wav file.
You just need to know the mathematics and sound engineering to produce the sound you want.
In this example the equation calculates a binaural beat.

```java
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final double sampleRate = 44100.0;
        final double frequency = 440;
        final double frequency2 = 90;
        final double amplitude = 1.0;
        final double seconds = 2.0;
        final double twoPiF = 2 * Math.PI * frequency;
        final double piF = Math.PI * frequency2;

        float[] buffer = new float[(int)(seconds * sampleRate)];

        for (int sample = 0; sample < buffer.length; sample++) {
            double time = sample / sampleRate;
            buffer[sample] = (float)(amplitude * Math.cos(piF * time) * Math.sin(twoPiF * time));
        }

        final byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[buffer.length * 2];

        int bufferIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < byteBuffer.length; i++) {
            final int x = (int)(buffer[bufferIndex++] * 32767.0);

            byteBuffer[i++] = (byte)x;
            byteBuffer[i] = (byte)(x >>> 8);
        }

        File out = new File("out10.wav");

        final boolean bigEndian = false;
        final boolean signed = true;

        final int bits = 16;
        final int channels = 1;

        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat((float)sampleRate, bits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteBuffer);
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(bais, format, buffer.length);
        AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, out);
        audioInputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Some more detail on what you'd like to achieve would be helpful. If raw WAV data is okay for you, simply use a FileInputStream and probably a Scanner to turn it into numbers. But let me try to give you some meaningful sample code to get you started:

There is a class called com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileWriter for this purpose.

```
InputStream in = ...;
OutputStream out = ...;

AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);

WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter();
writer.write(in, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, outStream);
```

You could implement your own AudioInputStream that does whatever voodoo to turn your number arrays into audio data.

```
writer.write(new VoodooAudioInputStream(numbers), AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, outStream);
```

As [@stacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241590/stacker) mentioned, you should get yourself familiar with the API of course.

Comment: My main problem was that voodoo itself. I wanted to see if there was ready code/class that did it.
I think I succeeded now, using AudioSystem and AudioInputStream. The trick was to reverse the order of bytes in each sound sample before I convert it to short, since WAV encodes the numeric values in little-Endian manner.
Thank you, Yonatan.

Answer (score 8):

The javax.sound.sample package is not suitable for processing WAV files if you need to have access to the actual sample values. The package lets you change volume, sample rate, etc., but if you want other effects (say, adding an echo), you are on your own. (The Java tutorial hints that it should be possible to process the sample values directly, but the tech writer overpromised.)

This site has a simple class for processing WAV files: http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html

Answer (score 6):

WAV File Specification 
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

There is an API for your purpose 
http://code.google.com/p/musicg/

Answer (score 3):

Wave files are supported by the [javax.sound.sample package](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html)

Since isn't a trivial API you should read an article / tutorial which introduces the API like

[Java Sound, An Introduction](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/1565671/Java-Sound-An-Introduction.htm)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you may need to know the headers and data positions of a WAVE structure, you can find the spec [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).
Be aware that the data are little endian.

There's an [API](http://code.google.com/p/musicg/) which may helps you to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I use `FileInputStream` with some magic:

```
    byte[] byteInput = new byte[(int)file.length() - 44];
    short[] input = new short[(int)(byteInput.length / 2f)];


    try{

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        fis.read(byteInput, 44, byteInput.length - 45);
        ByteBuffer.wrap(byteInput).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(input);

    }catch(Exception e  ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Your sample values are in `short[] input`!

Comment: what means: file.length() - 44 ...how did you get to those numbers

Comment: This is just really terrible code. WAV is a container that can hold pretty much any audio format (even mp3). There's no reason to assume that a WAV file holds 16-bit PCM. [It's also wrong to assume that the sound data appears at a fixed position in the file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19991594/2891664)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still can find it required, there is an audio framework I'm working on that aimed to solve that and similar issues. Though it's on Kotlin. You can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/WaveBeans/wavebeans

It would look like this:

```kotlin
wave("file:///path/to/file.wav")
    .map { it.asInt() } // here it as Sample type, need to convert it to desired type
    .asSequence(44100.0f) // framework processes everything as sequence/stream
    .toList() // read fully
    .toTypedArray() // convert to array
```

And it's not dependent on Java Audio.