# Reading wav file in Java

Tags: java, audio, wav, k-means

I want to read wav files in Java and I am going to classify them with K-means.

How can I read wav files in Java and assign them into an array or something like that(you can suggest ideas for it) to classify them?

**EDIT:** I want to use APIs for reading wav files and for K-means.

Comment: I think this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297749/java-reading-manipulating-and-writing-wav-files) will help you get started.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The official [Java Sound Programmer Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/contents.html) walks through [reading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/chapter7.html#a114527) and [writing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/chapter7.html#a114602) audio files.

This article by A Greensted: [Reading and Writing Wav Files in java](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html) should be helpful. The WavFile class is very useful and it can be tweaked to return the entire data array instead of buffered fragments.

Answer (score 3):

You could read the sound files using javax sound library and FileInputStream
([found a nice example here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1358705&page=9))
and treat the wave files as a vector of bits (0,1) or bytes.. using multiple sequence alignment ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment)) create a distance matrix between every stream of bits/bytes, and from there, the clustering should be straight forward.

The Problem is, that this method is very sensitive to noise, etc, but it is worth a shot...

Comment: Doing some noise reduction and perhaps downsampling would be a good idea. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Equivalent to matlab's wavread function:

http://web.archive.org/web/20120531113946/http://www.builogic.com/java/javasound-read-write.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help someone. Java JDK already provides [AudioSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html) class.

I used this as part of my tests to check generated WAV properties,

```
AudioFileFormat audioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(new File(response.get()));
assertEquals(1, audioFileFormat.getFormat().getChannels());
assertEquals(8000.0, audioFileFormat.getFormat().getSampleRate(), 0.0f);
assertEquals(8, audioFileFormat.getFormat().getSampleSizeInBits());
```