# Is it possible using mmio to read wave file in java?

Tags: java, windows

I'm already finished my code using delphi,but then i was wondering if i can use mmio windows function in java to read .wav file, is it even possible? if yes can u give me lead, because i can't found any source to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Comment: Then by default java can't right? thanks i'll try to learn this method

Comment: What you're asking can only be done with **native** code. Java can only run in a JVM. JNI is the standard Java way to interface with native libraries. This doesn't mean Java can't do that, but means you need native libraries and you can interface with those from Java through JNI.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are asking. MMIO typically refers to reading memory off of devices or reading from memory-mapped files. i.e. [MMIODevice](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/daapi/com/oracle/deviceaccess/mmio/MMIODevice.html)

You can process .wav files in Java to produce sound using multiple methods. Some examples: [Reading wav file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210147/reading-wav-file-in-java)