# How do you get the audio byte[] from the synthesised speech created by the TextToSpeech engine?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-audiomanager, visualizer

I'm trying to get the audio byte[] that's created when the TextToSpeech engine synthesises text.

I've tried creating a Visualiser and assigned a `OnDataCaptureListener` but the byte[] it provides is always the same, and therefore I don't believe the array is connected to the spoken text.

This is my implementation:

```
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            audioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusChange -> Log.d(TAG, "focusChange is: is: " + focusChange), AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);

            int audioSessionId = audioManager.generateAudioSessionId();

            mVisualizer = new Visualizer(audioSessionId);

            mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);

            mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[0]);

            mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(
            new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {

            public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
             byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {

                   //here the bytes are always equal to the bytes received in the last call
              }

              public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {

               }
             }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate(), true, true);

             mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
```

I also found that you can use the [SynthesisCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/SynthesisCallback.html) to receive the byte[] via its `audioAvailable()` method but I can't seem to implement it properly.

I created a `TextToSpeechService` but its `onSynthesizeText()` method is never called. However, I can tell that the service is working as the `onLoadLanguage()` is called.

**My question in a nutshell:** How do I get the audio bytes[] representation of the audio created when the TextToSpeech engine synthesis text?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could only find way that firstly stnthesizes the tts to a file and load the file again to the target buffer using wav reading library.

Answer (score 2):

I heard that `onAudioAvailable()` was deprecated and my callback is not called, too.

So a workaround is:

1. In Activity:

   ```
   try
       {
           tts.shutdown();
           tts = null;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {}
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
   ```
2. In `OnInit()` method:

   ```
      @Override
       public void onInit(int p1)
       {

        HashMap<String,String> mTTSMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
       tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener()
               { 
                   @Override
                   public void onStart(final String p1)
                   {
                       // TODO: Implement this method
                           Log.e(TAG, "START");
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onDone(final String p1)
                   {
                       if (p1.compareTo("abcde") == 0)
                       {
                           synchronized (MainActivity.this)
                           {
                               MainActivity.this.notifyAll();
                           }
                       }
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(final String p1)
                   {       
                        //this is also deprecated...
                   }
                   @Override
                   public void onAudioAvailable(final String id, final byte[] bytes)
                   {
             //never calked!
                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                               @Override
                               public void run()
                               {
                                   // TODO: Implement this method
                                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "id:" + id  /*"bytes:" + Arrays.toString(bytes)*/, 1).show();
                                   Log.v(TAG, "BYTES");
                               }});
                       //super.onAudioAvailable(id,bytes);

                   }

               });

           Locale enEn = new Locale("en_EN");
           if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(enEn) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
           {
               tts.setLanguage(enEn);
           }

           /*public int synthesizeToFile(java.lang.CharSequence text, android.os.Bundle params, java.io.File file, java.lang.String utteranceId);*/
           //@java.lang.Deprecated()
           // public int synthesizeToFile(java.lang.String text, java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> params, java.lang.String filename);
                 mTTSMap.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "abcde"); tts.synthesizeToFile("Hello",mTTSMap,"/storage/emulated/0/a.wav");
   synchronized(MainActivity.this){
                    try{
                         MainActivity.this.wait();
                        }catch(InterruptedException e){}
                        ReadTheFile();    
                    }
           }
   ```

Then your work is to load the a.wav to the buffer you want. Using libraries like that was mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5211299/8614565).

Summary:

1. Create TTS Engine.
2. Initialize it.
3. `OnInit` is called.
4. In `OnInit()`, you setup a new HashMap and put utterence id.
5. Register `setOnUtteranceProgressListener`.
6. Synthesize something to a file.
7. Call `wait();`
8. In `onDone()` method call `notify();`
9. After the `wait();` read the synthesized file to a buffer.