# How can I detect whether a WAV file has a 44 or 46-byte header?

Tags: audio, wav

I've discovered it is dangerous to assume that all PCM wav audio files have 44 bytes of header data before the samples begin. Though this is common, many applications (ffmpeg for example), will generate wavs with a 46-byte header and ignoring this fact while processing will result in a corrupt and unreadable file. But how can you detect how long the header actually is?

Obviously there is a way to do this, but I searched and found little discussion about this. A LOT of audio projects out there assume 44 (or conversely, 46) depending on the authors own context.

Comment: I have a lot of WAV files where the data starts somewhere else entirely: maybe hundreds of bytes from the start of the file, who knows?  The WAV chunk headers are actually easy to parse, you have no excuse for not parsing them.

Comment: It's true there is no excuse for parsing the header, but there is a lot of misinformation out there about doing so. Search for "wav parser" on Google and many of top hits contain code that assumes 44-byte length with no discussion. SO contained only hints toward something larger. I'm try to draw attention to this issue for the next frustrated person who goes looking.

Comment: I've always found that the [WAVE PCM soundfile format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) page on the Center for Computer Research in Music and Acoustics (Standford) website to be a useful resource for this type of thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick is to look at the "Subchunk1Size", which is a 4-byte integer beginning at byte 16 of the header. In a normal 44-byte wav, this integer will be 16 [10, 0, 0, 0]. If it's a 46-byte header, this integer will be 18 [12, 0, 0, 0] or maybe even higher if there is extra extensible meta data (rare?).

The extra data itself (if present), begins in byte 36.

So a simple C# program to detect the header length would look like this:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    fileStream.Seek(16, 0);
    fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
    fileStream.Close();
    int Subchunk1Size = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

    if (Subchunk1Size < 16)
        Console.WriteLine("This is not a valid wav file");
    else
        switch (Subchunk1Size)
        {
            case 16:
                Console.WriteLine("44-byte header");
                break;
            case 18:
                Console.WriteLine("46-byte header");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Header contains extra data and is larger than 46 bytes");
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

You should be checking all of the header data to see what the actual sizes are. Broadcast Wave Format files will contain an even larger extension subchunk. WAV and AIFF files from Pro Tools have even more extension chunks that are undocumented as well as data after the audio. If you want to be sure where the sample data begins and ends you need to actually look for the data chunk ('data' for WAV files and 'SSND' for AIFF).

As a review, all WAV subchunks conform to the following format:

```
Subchunk Descriptor (4 bytes)
    Subchunk Size (4 byte integer, little endian)
    Subchunk Data (size is Subchunk Size)
```

This is very easy to process. All you need to do is read the descriptor, if it's not the one you are looking for, read the data size and skip ahead to the next. A simple Java routine to do that would look like this:

```java
//
// Quick note for people who don't know Java well:
// 'in.read(...)' returns -1 when the stream reaches
// the end of the file, so 'if (in.read(...) < 0)'
// is checking for the end of file.
//
public static void printWaveDescriptors(File file)
        throws IOException {
    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];

        // Read first 4 bytes.
        // (Should be RIFF descriptor.)
        if (in.read(bytes) < 0) {
            return;
        }

        printDescriptor(bytes);

        // First subchunk will always be at byte 12.
        // (There is no other dependable constant.)
        in.skip(8);

        for (;;) {
            // Read each chunk descriptor.
            if (in.read(bytes) < 0) {
                break;
            }

            printDescriptor(bytes);

            // Read chunk length.
            if (in.read(bytes) < 0) {
                break;
            }

            // Skip the length of this chunk.
            // Next bytes should be another descriptor or EOF.
            int length = (
                  Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[0])
                | Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[1]) << 8
                | Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[2]) << 16
                | Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes[3]) << 24
            );
            in.skip(Integer.toUnsignedLong(length));
        }

        System.out.println("End of file.");
    }
}

private static void printDescriptor(byte[] bytes)
        throws IOException {
    String desc = new String(bytes, "US-ASCII");
    System.out.println("Found '" + desc + "' descriptor.");
}
```

For example here is a random WAV file I had:

```
Found 'RIFF' descriptor.
Found 'bext' descriptor.
Found 'fmt ' descriptor.
Found 'minf' descriptor.
Found 'elm1' descriptor.
Found 'data' descriptor.
Found 'regn' descriptor.
Found 'ovwf' descriptor.
Found 'umid' descriptor.
End of file.
```

Notably, here both 'fmt ' and 'data' legitimately appear in between other chunks because [Microsoft's RIFF specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that subchunks can appear in any order. Even some major audio systems that I know of get this wrong and don't account for that.

So if you want to find a certain chunk, loop through the file checking each descriptor until you find the one you're looking for.

Comment: Radiodef, thanks for your comment!
I never used bit shifting before and can't find practical use examples in web. Could you please explain what this expression does why bit shifting is used here?


<code>
(bytes[0] & 0xFF)
| (bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 8
| (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 16
| (bytes[3] & 0xFF) << 24
</code>

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: @RomanM It converts 4 bytes to a 32-bit integer. For example, a 32-bit integer `00000000000000001000000010000001` (decimal 32897) could be split in to four bytes, `00000000`, `00000000`, `10000000` and `10000001`. The code with bit shifting takes bytes and creates a 32-bit integer out of them, by shifting each byte in to place and then combining them with bitwise OR. The `& 0xFF` part is specific to Java, and [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11380062/2891664).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Radiodef's excellent reply, I'd like to add 3 things that aren't obvious.

1. The only rule for WAV files is the FMT chunk comes before the DATA chunk.  Apart from that, you will find chunks you don't know about at the beginning, before the DATA chunk and after it.  You must read the header for each chunk to skip forward to find the next chunk.
2. The FMT chunk is commonly found in 16 byte and 18 byte variations, but the spec actually allows more than 18 bytes as well.
   If the FMT chunk' header size field says greater than 16, Bytes 17 and 18 also specify how many extra bytes there are, so if they are both zero, you end up with an 18 byte FMT chunk identical to the 16 byte one.
   It is safe to read in just the first 16 bytes of the FMT chunk and parse those, ignoring any more.
   Why does this matter? - not much any more, but Windows XP's Media Player was able to play 16 bit WAV files, but 24 bit WAV files only if the FMT chunk was the Extended (18+ byte) version.  There used to be a lot of complaints that "Windows doesn't play my 24 bit WAV files", but if it had an 18 byte FMT chunk, it would...    Microsoft fixed that sometime during the early days of Windows 7, so 24 bit with 16 byte FMT files work fine now.
3. (Newly added)  Chunk sizes with odd sizes occur quite often. Mostly seen when a 24 bit mono file is made.   It is unclear from the spec, but the chunk size specifies the actual data length (the odd value) and a pad byte (zero) is added after the chunk and before the start of the next chunk.  So chunks always start on even boundaries, but the chunk size itself is stored as the actual odd value.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a summary of some of the complexity in the 'fmt ' chunk that I've discovered.  It's really a good idea to understand how to parse this chunk, specifically, if you're handling WAV files, and there are some quirks that you should be prepared to deal with.

First, here's the general format of a chunk in a RIFF file, such as .wav:

```
typedef struct _wav_chunk {
    char      id[4];          // 4-byte ID
    uint32_t  sz;             // Size of chunk data (excl. header)
  //char     *data;           // Chunk data, of length 'sz'
  //char      pad;            // Padding byte
} wav_chunk;
```

Chunks come one right after the other.  4 bytes of printable ASCII characters, padded on the right -- and *only* on the right -- by spaces, if necessary.  A 32-bit size field, in little-endian order.  Then the chunk's arbitrary data, which is 'sz' bytes long.  The smallest possible chunk is 8 bytes long, with sz == 0.

The next chunk would be found right after, although it's important to note that chunks SHOULD always be aligned to 16-bit boundaries.  So, if a chunk ends up an odd size, it's obligatory to pad it by a single byte at the end.  But, do expect to see this rule broken.  I make it a point to look for a chunk at the very next byte, and one byte after that, just in case.  You might have to use some heuristics, by ensuring the ID is all ASCII, doesn't start with a space or 0x00, and is followed by four bytes that look like a 32-bit integer -- first field is either non-zero, or all four fields are zeroes.  That kind of thing.

It's also possible for chunks to contain chunks.  In this case, the "parent" chunk will have a 'sz' field that accommodates the total size of all "child" chunks, so you can skip over it even if you don't understand what it is, and that it's supposed to be hierarchical.  If you DO know that chunk by its ID, you will know to descend into it, normally by finding a sub-chunk ID right after the 'sz' field of the parent.

OK, so let's look at the definition of the 'fmt ' chunk itself:

```
typedef struct _wav_fmt_chunk {
    uint16_t  samp_format;    // PCM: 0x01, Float: 0x03, Ext: 0xFFFE
    uint16_t  channels;       // 1 or 2, usually
    uint32_t  samp_rate;      // E.g., 44100
    uint32_t  bytes_sec;      // Data rate, bytes/sec
    uint16_t  blocksz;        // Size of one sample, in bytes
    uint16_t  bits_samp;      // Bits per sample (e.g. 8,16,24..)
    uint16_t  extsz;          // Extension size (0 or more bytes)
    uint16_t  valid_bps;      // Valid bits per sample
    uint32_t  chan_mask;      // Channel mapping
    uint16_t  codec;          // Extended format codec (GUID [0:1])
    char      guid[14];       // Remaining 14 byte of GUID
} wav_fmt_chk;
```

The 16-byte version is just the first six fields (nothing after bits_samp.)  The 18-byte version includes 'extsz', but it's set to 0.  The Extensible format yields extsz == 22, which uses the rest of the fields in this struct.  This describes more complex sample formats and codecs (e.g., MP3 frames, or old ADPCM formats, etc.)

Generally, the size fields are redundant and should be equal to the product of the fields that describe the sample format, like this:

```
// Round bits_samp up to a whole number of bytes
bytes_per_sample = (fmt.bits_samp / 8);

if (fmt.bits_samp % 8) {
    bytes_per_sample++;
}

// Blocksz -- size of one sample, in bytes
fmt.blocksz = fmt.channels * bytes_per_sample;

// Bytes_sec -- data rate in bytes/sec
fmt.bytes_sec = fmt.blocksz * fmt.samp_rate;
```

I'll get to the rest of the fields in a moment.

Notice the bits_samp field may not be an even number of bytes -- like with 18-bit and 20-bit samples.  In this case, you must round up to the nearest whole number of bytes.

A bog-standard 16-bit, 44.1kHz, stereo PCM wave file can just use the 16-byte simple fmt chunk.  The specification recommends or requires the extended version (at least 18-byte) for bit depths over 16-bit, for any non-PCM sample formats, including floating point, when using a channel count higher than 2 (stereo), or a channel map other than "mono" or "stereo", and when samples are padded, such as when 24-bit samples are stored in 32-bit blocks.

Now, there are lots of files out there that break these rules in various ways, and various implementations handle them with various results!

For example, it's quite common to see 24-bit PCM or Float samples in a simple header, which is technically incorrect.  Some old audio editors (like Cool Edit) would use 24-bit samples in 32-bit blocks, but since there wasn't a way to describe this packing (this was before the extended fmt chunk was designed), it would just set bits_samp == 24.  You would have to compare the blocksz field to the calculated block alignment to see the discrepancy.

This last example is particularly pertinent, because the revised specification mandates that bits_samp is always the actual number of bits used to store a sample, even if not all those bits are used.  Hence the addition of valid_bps, which then clarifies how many bits are significant.  (Padding bits should always be on the least-significant end.)

**This is subtle and important:**  If you are dealing with a file that has an 18-byte (or larger) fmt chunk, bits_samp *should* accurately describe the size of one block of samples, using valid_bps if necessary to convey how many are significant.  BUT, if you are dealing with a 16-byte fmt chunk, you should be prepared to interpret bits_samp as more like valid_bps, and calculate the real sample size from (blocksz / channels).

The chan_mask field is a bitmap, which describes which known speaker positions the interleaved samples should be routed to.  The samples should be routed in the same order as the bitmap.  If chan_mask == 0, then you just route mono files to L+R, stereo files to L,R, and multichannel files to the outputs of the audio device in the order defined by the audio driver (ch1 to output1, ch2 to output2, etc.)

The codec field is kind of a duplicate of format, used when format == 0xFFFE (extensible).  This field is actually the first two bytes of the 16-byte GUID, so another valid interpretation would be to drop this field and make GUID a 16-byte char array.

The guid field contains the remaining 14 bytes, which, for well-known codecs, will usually be 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0xaa 0x00 0x38 0x9b 0x71.

It might be tempting to do the bare minimum when interpreting the fmt chunk, but if you do, you should be very careful to only proceed when the format is PCM, and the fmt chunk size is either 16 or 18, and then validate the contents look sensible.

Even without considering the plethora of non-PCM formats (which are a whole other ball of wax), this can get surprisingly messy to do correctly.  And to be honest, it's always going to be a bit of a crapshoot.  The specification just wasn't flexible enough at first, which led to some "creative" solutions that became common to see in the wild.  Most of the files you will run across should be simple, and even given the surprising ambiguity of the specification that continues to endure today, you should not have much trouble interpreting the essential chunks.  Still, it would definitely be wise to run some sanity checks (calculating blocksz and bytes_sec yourself, and ensuring they equal the values in the header) to verify the file is compliant, and so is your code.

Now, also consider that it's actually possible to store the sample data in *multiple* data chunks, and use things like playlists to sequence them (and blocks of silence -- which, technically, should repeat the last valid sample value, not necessarily 0.)  There are also 64-bit extensions to overcome the 4GB limit.  Did I mention there's even a RIFX format for use with Big-Endian encoding...?