# C++ read wav file, subchunk1size = 65536?

Tags: audio, wav

I wrote a program that read information from a .wav file . I received the following results.

```
chunkId            :RIFF
chunkSize          :7828798
format             :WAVE
Junk chunk         :JUNK
Junk size          :92
Format chunk       :fmt 
format chunk size  :65536
Audioformat        :1
numberofchanels    :48000
samplerate         :1996488704
Byterate           :131073
BlockAlign         :16
bitspersample      :0
subchunk2Id        :
subchunk2Size      :0
```

I don't know why wav header like that. I use sox program to look header of this wav file .
And here is result

```
Input File     : 'AUDIO00001.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:01:17.28 = 3709621 samples ~ 5796.28 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 7.83M
Bit Rate       : 810k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

Why's my program wrong??

I update my question:
my wav header structure:

```
struct WAVHEADER
    {
        char                chunkID[4];
        unsigned int        chunkSize;
        char                format[4];

        char                junkChunk[4];
        int                 junkSize;
        char                junkData[92];
        char                bext[4];
        unsigned int        bextSize;
        char                bextData[602];
        char                subchunk1ID[4];
        unsigned int        subchunk1Size;
        unsigned short      audioFormat;
        unsigned short      numberOfChanels;
        unsigned int        sampleRate;
        unsigned int        byteRate;
        unsigned short      blockAlign;
        unsigned short      bitsPerSample;
        char                subchunk2ID[4];
        unsigned int        subchunk2Size;
};
```

wav class:

```
wav::wav(const char* filepath)
{
    std::ifstream wavFile(filepath);
    if(wavFile.is_open())
    {
        wavFile.read((char*)&wavHeader,sizeof(WAVHEADER));

    }
}
```

My confusing is that when subChunk1ID is correct ("fmt") , why does subchunk1Size seem wrong ??

Comment: It looks like you missed a field. See how your 48000 ended up in numberofchannels instead of samplerate?

Comment: Where did you get the file? Also, show us the code you are using to read it.

Comment: Here is my wav file Link.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/81enwjr8kg79msc/AUDIO00001.wav

Answer (score 0):

The compiler seems to insert 2 bytes of padding between `subchunk1ID` and `subchunk1Size`. This is my hypothesis because

- what you are seeing is that the struct is shifted 2 bytes "to the left"
- and when I tested this I noticed that `sizeof(WAVHEADER)` was 2 bytes larger than it should be.

I'm not a C++ compiler expert so I can't tell you why it does that except that certainly it's allowed to do so.

To show visually, what the struct should look like at that point is this:

```
...
subchunk1ID:
    01100110
    01101101
    01110100
    00100000
subchunk1Size:
    00101000
    00000000
    00000000
    00000000
audioFormat:
    00000001
    00000000
numberOfChanels:
    00000001
    00000000
...
```

But instead what you are getting is this:

```
...
subchunk1ID:
    01100110
    01101101
    01110100
    00100000
2 bytes of pad:
    00101000
    00000000
subchunk1Size:
    00000000
    00000000
    00000001
    00000000
audioFormat:
    00000001
    00000000
...
```

`00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000` is the number 65536 in little endian byte order.

So really what you have found is that this struct casting is not a reliable way to read a file. You should read it "the hard way" instead (one number at a time). There are other pitfalls like this one such as:

- Endianness.
- [Existence, size and ordering of particular subchunks is not consistent in a WAV file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19991594/2891664) There is no reason `JUNK` and `bext` need to appear in the file, nor do they need to be sizes known at compile time of the program.