# Reading .wav signal in matlab and java

Tags: java, android, matlab

When I loaded .wav signal in matlab,the values ​​of samples are like this 0.001853466033936, 0.003706693649292 etc.

When I loaded same signal in Java with:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
FileInputStream s = new FileInputStream(file);
s.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);
```

i have values like this: 73, 70...

I tried to convert to double and I never got the same result like in matlab.

I need this for Android!

Can someone help me? THANKS!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297749/java-reading-manipulating-and-writing-wav-files

Comment: This is ok, but I need that for android, AudioInputStream and javax.sound are not suported there.

Comment: You definitely should mention it in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your java code is reading the file from the beginning. Look at the [WAVE file format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/), the data is stored after the header.

You will need to write a wav file reader (or find an android compatible one) to parse the header, read the `NumChannels`, `BitsPerSample` etc, find the start of the data and read.

This is what MATLAB's `wavread` does (presumably this is what you are using?). You can see how it parses wav files, type `edit wavread`.

Have a look at this simple [Java WAV File IO](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html) class. It may do all you need or at least get you started.