# Extract audio track from mp4 and save it to a playable audio file

Tags: java, android, audio, mediaextractor

The following code is my work which can extract the audio track and save it to a file in android. However, I don't know how to encode the audio track to be a playable audio file (e.g., .m4a or .aac). In addition, I also read the format information of the audio track {mime=audio/mp4a-latm, aac-profile=2, channel-count=2, track-id=2, profile=2, max-input-size=610, durationUs=183600181, csd-0=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=2 cap=2], sample-rate=44100}.

```
            MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();

            try
            {
                extractor.setDataSource("input.mp4");

                int numTracks = extractor.getTrackCount();
                int audioTrackIndex = -1;

                for (int i = 0; i < numTracks; ++i)
                {
                    MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
                    String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);

                    if (mime.equals("audio/mp4a-latm"))
                    {
                        audioTrackIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Extract audio
                if (audioTrackIndex >= 0)
                {
                    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(500 * 1024);
                    File audioFile = new File("output_audio_track");
                    FileOutputStream audioOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(audioFile);

                    extractor.selectTrack(audioTrackIndex);

                    while (true)
                    {
                        int readSampleCount = extractor.readSampleData(byteBuffer, 0);

                        if (readSampleCount < 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        // Save audio file
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[readSampleCount];
                        byteBuffer.get(buffer);
                        audioOutputStream.write(buffer);
                        byteBuffer.clear();
                        extractor.advance();
                    }

                    audioOutputStream.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                extractor.release();
            }
```

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3297889/5288316) to save your AudioOutputStream to a WAV file.

Comment: AFAIK an aac raw stream cannot be played. you have to add metadata required for each frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the audio stream without re-encoding:

ffmpeg -i input-video.mp4 -vn -acodec copy output-audio.aac

-vn is no video.
-acodec copy says use the same audio stream that's already in there.

Read the output to see what codec it is, to set the right filename extension.